# Remove the Back to Listings tag?

Tags: profile

I have set up a profile that only displays membership information (view).  It works great and shows me the current status and fields for the logged in user as expected.  However, at the bottom of this profile it displays " Back to Listings    "  -- we did not initiate it from a list so clicking it returns a listing of all members for other members to view (not what I want).  How can I remove this tag?

TIA
Norm